# Данные из нескольких таблиц и подсчет суммы столбцов

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть следующая структура БД

```
CREATE TABLE `student` (
    `id_student` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `last_name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `middle_name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_stud`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=5
;

CREATE TABLE `table2` (
    `id_student` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `pole1` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `pole2` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `pole3` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_student`),
    CONSTRAINT `table2_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_student`) REFERENCES `student` (`id_student`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;

CREATE TABLE `table3` (
    `id_student` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `pole1` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `pole2` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `pole3` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_student`),
    CONSTRAINT `table3_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_student`) REFERENCES `student` (`id_student`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

Нужно  вывести всех студентов и сделать подсчет данных в таблицах table2, table3. Сложить в одной таблице 3 поля (pole1,pole2,pole3) и в другой, а потом между собой. Я сделал запрос который слаживает поля только если есть записи в таблицах(table1,table2). А мне нужно вывести всех студентов даже если нету записей в таблицах то выводить просто 0.

### Вот такая структура должна получиться:

### last_name|name|middle_name|Suma=(pole1+pole2+pole3+pole1+pole2+pole3)|

```
SELECT st.last_name, st.name, st.middle_name, st.room, 
    (t2.pole1+t2.pole2+t2.pole3)
FROM student as st, table2 as t2
WHERE del.id_d = st.id_stud;
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [внешнее соединение](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_explicit_join_operations.html) и [COALESCE](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_case_statement/page2.html).